# TestNG in Eclipse for Selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am beginner to selenium and learning to use TestNG in selenium.
I have created a very simple program using TestNG but I am not getting the option in suggestions  to add "TestNG library file" in my program that is why my program is not probably giving me option to Run as "TestNG".

Please anybody can help me out with this.

[image: TestNG in eclipse - my program image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please insert the code you used directly into your question, do *not* use an image of the code instead. To format the code properly, select it and click on the "blockquote" symbol in the editor: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks . BTW, your image does not show the code anyway;)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is pretty correct.

As you are trying to add `@Test` Annotation to the method your `IDE` is providing you suggestions whether you would prefer to **import** **`@Test` Annotation** from **org.testng.annotations** or from **org.junit**.

### Solution

On selecting **org.testng.annotations**, **`import org.testng.annotations.Test;`** would be added to your `Class` file automatically by the `IDE`.

Comment: Yes, I have imported the "org.testng.annotations" package for @Test Annotation that I am using, but then it is not giving me option to run the program as "TestNG" which i think is because of i haven't added the testNG library file to my program. My understanding is if i add testNG library file than only i will get the option of "run as TestNG"

Comment: @shikha As your IDE is auto suggesting TestNG you should be fine to execute with TestNG annotation. But if you want to execute as TestNG suite through testng.xml you have to convert into TestNG Test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it as TestNg test then you ll have to convert your project to TestNg project. For that you ll have to install TestNg framework in your eclipse.

**Steps to do the same:**

1) In eclipse, under help tab > click on "Install new Software"
2) Enter `http://beust.com/eclipse` and allow TestNg packages to load.
3) Select those packages and do the normal installation procedure.
4) Keep patience and follow all the steps.
5) Restart eclipse and now when you ll run your test you ll be able to see option as Run as > TestNg test.

Let me know in case of any concerns.